# how to chain methods in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to implement a parsing method to turn an XML document into a multi-dimensional array, however it relies on needing to removal objects from an array just after adding that array to the multi-dimensional array, like so:

```
while (k<blockRowArray.count){                                   //loops through all rows one by one
        NSLog(@"current k is %i", k);
        GDataXMLDocument *currentRow = (GDataXMLDocument *) [blockRowArray objectAtIndex:k];
        NSArray *arrayOfBlocks = [currentRow nodesForXPath:@"b" error:nil];
        j = 0;
        while (j <arrayOfBlocks.count) {
            NSLog(@"current j is %i",j);
            GDataXMLElement *blockElement = (GDataXMLElement *) [arrayOfBlocks objectAtIndex:j];
            NSNumber* blockValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[blockElement stringValue] intValue]];
            [individualRowOfBlocks addObject:blockValue];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
        NSLog (@"Current row of blocks array is %@",individualRowOfBlocks);


        [rowBlocks addObject:individualRowOfBlocks];
        [individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects];
    }
```

However `[individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects]` is clearly running at the same time or before `[rowBlocks addObject:individualRowOfBlocks]` as I end up with a multi-dimensional array with a set of empty arrays in it, so what I need to do is make sure that `[individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects]` runs after `[individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects]` any methods of doing this?

Comment: why don't you use a library for that?

Comment: I couldn't find any advice or tutorials or answers on here about how to do it anywhere online so I've been developing off a tutorial I did a while back which uses GDataXMLNode, and then parses it in a similar way to this, that's why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However [individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects] is clearly running at
>   the same time or before [rowBlocks addObject:individualRowOfBlocks] as
>   I end up with a multi-dimensional array with a set of empty arrays in
>   it, so what I need to do is make sure that [individualRowOfBlocks
>   removeAllObjects] runs after [individualRowOfBlocks removeAllObjects]
>   any methods of doing this?

Unless there are threads (or queues) involved, Objective-C methods are always going to be executed in the order written in the code *unless the methods being called explicitly do stuff in threads/queues in their implementation* (which is exceptionally unlikely in that code).

Every time you call `[rowBlocks addObject:individualRowOfBlocks];`, you are adding a new reference to the same `individualRowOfBlocks` array.   If you subsequently change the contents of `individualRowOfBlocks`, every slot in `rowBlocks` will effectively reflect that change because *every slot points to the same instance of the array*.

It sounds like instead of `removeAllObjects`, you should create a new instance of `NSMutableArray` on each pass through the loop, assigning it to `individualRowOfBlocks`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes of course because they're pointers to values not the actual values! damn, thank you for that! ok I'll give that a go, and more than likely mark you as correct when I can!

Comment: You, good sir, are my favourite person in the world right now! :P

Comment: Happy to help!  Also, when you call `copy` on collections, it doesn't do a deep copy.  Only the collection is copied, not the contained objects.